# Counting the number of pairs of items in a grouped dataframe's column. (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, combinations

I would like to count the number of pairs of items in a column. I made my solution for it, but I would like to know if there are more concise solutions.

Here is an example and my approach.
I have a DataFrame like this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,2,2], 'item':['apple','orange','orange','apple']})
```

Finally, I would like to know what items are bought most together. Therefore, in this case, I'd like to get a result that orange and apple are bought most together.

Then, I did groupby based on values in `id` column.

```
id_group = df.groupby('id')
```

Then, to count the number of pairs of items in `item` column, I made a function like below and applied to `item` column of `id_group`. After this, I combined lists of tuples using `sum()`. Finally, I used `Counter()`  to count the number of pairs containing same items. 
In `combos()`, I used `sorted()`to avoid counting `('apple','orange')` and `('orange','apple')` separately.

Are there better approaches to get the result showing there are 2 pairs of `('apple','orange')` or 2 pairs of `('orange','apple')`

```
import itertools 
from collections import Counter
def combos(x):
     combinations = []
     num = x.size
     while num != 1:
          combinations += list(itertools.combinations(x,num))
          num -= 1
     element_sorted = map(sorted,combinations)
     return list(map(tuple,element_sorted))

k= id_group['item'].apply(lambda x:combos(x)).sum()
Counter(k)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `all_subsets` function with change `0` to `2` for pairs, triples... like your soluton:

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/5898031
from itertools import chain, combinations
def all_subsets(ss):
    return chain(*map(lambda x: combinations(ss, x), range(2, len(ss)+1)))
```

And then flatten values, I think better is not use `sum` to concatenate lists. It looks fancy but it's quadratic and should be considered bad practice.

So here is used flattening with sorted tuples in list comprehension:

```
k = [tuple(sorted(z)) for y in id_group['item'].apply(all_subsets) for z in y]

print (Counter(k))
Counter({('apple', 'orange'): 2})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your very helpful answer ! I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Sherlock_Hound - Solution was unaccepted, there is some problem?

Comment: I apologize for messing up. I guess that  `sorted(y)` in the list comprehension do not change the order of items in tuples. When I ran the code, I still got `Counter({('apple', 'orange'): 1, ('orange', 'apple'): 1})`.

Comment: @Sherlock_Hound - You are right, sorry, edited answer.

Comment: You don't have to be sorry. What you have done was really helpful! And It is my fault that I did not actually run your code. Thank you!

Comment: @Sherlock_Hound - No problem, now working and it is super ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
from collections import Counter
k = df.groupby('id')['item'].apply(lambda x: tuple(x.sort_values()))
Counter(k)

Counter({('apple', 'orange'): 2})
```

Comment: I think you mentioned that you are not sure about what I want to do. Sorry about that. I edited my question a little bit. I hope that it will help.  And I really appreciate your contribution.

Comment: Np, I think @Jezrael's solution is the way to go :-)